# Index of range with multiple non-sequential columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Consider the following VBA MWE

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A:A, C:C")

Dim rRow As Range

For i = 1 To 5
    Set rRow = Intersect(rng, rng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
    rRow.Value = 1
    rRow.Cells(, 2).Value = 2
Next
End Sub
```

Which produces an output that looks like this

```
1   2   1
1   2   1
1   2   1
1   2   1
1   2   1
```

As we can see, the line `rRow.Value = 1` sets the cells in the first and third column to 1. Now, I can't get my head around why the `rRow.Cells(1,2)` doesn't access the third column such that the output is

```
1       2
1       2
1       2
1       2
1       2
```

and leave the second column empty, since this appears to be what is happening in the line `rRow.Value = 1`. Can someone explain this logic to me?

EDIT:

Commenting out the `rRow.Cells(,2).Value = 2` such that the code reads

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A:A, C:C")

Dim rRow As Range

For i = 1 To 5
    Set rRow = Intersect(rng, rng.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
    rRow.Value = 1
    'rRow.Cells(, 2).Value = 2
Next


End Sub
```

yields the following output

```
1       1
1       1
1       1
1       1
1       1
```

where columns A and C are filled with ones, and column B is left alone.

Comment: I was expecting the `rng` object indexes to reflect on the entire definition of the object, defining `A` as the first column and `C` as the second, such that it would differ from `Range("A1:C5")`.

Comment: Nope.Cells() always returns a single cell, in any context whasoever. rng.Cells(row, col) returns the single cell at (row, col) within the range, couting from top to down for the row and from left to right for the col, relatively to the top and left of the range.

Comment: Then how does `rRow.Value` in the above example access only row 1 and 3?

Comment: No, it modified all the cells of the range rRow. But later, you overwrote the second cell in the next statement :)

Comment: Allow me to update my question

Comment: Ah ok, that is because your definition of the rRow excluded the column B. If you want it to include the columns A, B and C, you should define it as `Range("A:C")`. But again, dont be surprized that referencing the cells(, 2) yields a cell that is second to the left of the range. the cells method just Range.Cells computes relatively to the TopLeft of a range, doesnt check if the result is within the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Range` or `Cells` property of a `Range` object (rather than the more usual `Worksheet`), provides a reference to a range relative to the top left cell of the original range. It is not in any way restricted to cells within that original range.
Hence this:

```
Range("A1").Range("B2")
```

refers to the cell one column to the right and one row below A1. So does this:

```
Range("A1:A10").Range("B2")
```

Note that it still only refers to **one cell**, even though the original range was 10 cells. `Cells` works in exactly the same way (just as it does with a `Worksheet` parent). So this:

```
Range("A1").Cells(2, 2)
```

and this:

```
Range("A1:A10").Cells(2, 2)
```

both refer to B2.

Comment: Is it possible to define a `Range` or any other object that would have index properties from the object "contents" rather than the reference, as you described? For instance, such that the index 1 is column A, index 2 is column C and index 3 is out of bounds?

Comment: No. The only way to restrict yourself to the original range is to use a `For each cell in range.cells` loop.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped to avoid a loop, but this is answers my question :-)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you can loop through the `Areas` of the range, load each into an array, process it, and dump it back out again.