# Range, Cells (and Item) in non sequential ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking at Holene question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009949/index-of-range-with-multiple-non-sequential-columns-in-vba) and while trying to understand the MSDN documentation I came into the following problem. could some one explain why the following lines give two different results?

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print "With Cells(2)"
    Debug.Print Intersect(Range("B:B, C:C"), Rows(1)).Cells(2).Address 'prints $C$1
    Debug.Print Intersect(Range("B:B, D:D"), Rows(1)).Cells(2).Address 'prints $B$2
    Debug.Print Range("B:B, C:C").Cells(2).Address 'prints $B$2
    Debug.Print Range("B:B, D:D").Cells(2).Address 'prints $B$2
    Debug.Print "With Item(2)"
    Debug.Print Intersect(Range("B:B, C:C"), Rows(1)).Item(2).Address 'prints $C$1
    Debug.Print Intersect(Range("B:B, D:D"), Rows(1)).Item(2).Address 'prints $B$2
    Debug.Print Range("B:B, C:C").Item(2).Address 'prints $B$2
    Debug.Print Range("B:B, D:D").Item(2).Address 'prints $B$2
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry @A.S.H I don't understand your comment. Wasn't you answer accepted some time ago?

Comment: This was sent to the wrong place, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many VBA Range methods work perfectly on a contiguous range, but have special behavior when the range has multiple areas, that is, they apply to the first area of the range. Cells(i) is one of them, although when spanning the range with a loop in the sort `For Each cell in myRange` they will work correctly and span all the cells even if the range has multiple areas.

In the first line of your test, the Intersect method has returned a contiguous range B1:C1, so naturally, Item 2 is C1. Because the cells(i) with one parameter spans the area row by row from left to right.

In the second line, the Intersect method has returned a multiple-area range: (B1, D1). so Cells(i) applies only on the first area, which is B1.

ps: Range.Cells(), while working this way, does not check whether the returned cell belongs to the original range.

**Edit:** To answer about the third line

In the third line, The definition of (B:B, C:C) is a multiple-area range, first area is row B, second area is Row C. For a human this would be equivalent to (B:C), but not for the compiler. The compiler does not try to merge areas when a range is defined, because such operation is computationally intensive and difficult in the general case. It just doesnt try to merge areas automatically when a range is defined, it follows the programmer's definition. I prefer it like that: follow the programmer's logic and stay fast.

Comment: Ok, but then why the third line did not return C1? "B:B, C:C" is contiguous, so the cell returned should be the one on the right of the top-left one, isn't it?

Comment: @VincentG The definition of (B:B, C:C) is a multiple-area range, first area is row B, second area is Row C. Dont be surprised that the compiler did not make enough effort to recognize that these areas can be merged into one area. It is computationally intensive. It just doesnt try to merge areas automatically when a range is defined, it follows the programmer's definition. I prefer it like that, follow the programmer's logic and stay fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not supply both a row and column index to `Cells`, it will iterate left to right, top to bottom through the **first area** of the specified range.

If the index you pass is greater than the number of cells in that range, the pattern is continued, restricting the area traversed *based on the number of columns in the original range*.

So if you use:

```
Range("A1:C1").Cells(3).address
```

you get $C$1. If you pass 4 as the index, it loops down to the next row and you get $A$2.

Note that if you exceed the number of available cells in the entire columns of the first area, you will get an error. So:

```
Range("A1").Cells(rows.Count).address
```

will return $A$1048576, but if you use:

```
Range("A1").Cells(rows.Count + 1).address
```

you get an error and not $B$1 because the range is limited to the width of the first area and height of the worksheet (i.e. the whole of column A).

Comment: As I commented on A.S.H answer, I understand that (that was what I deduced from your answer on Holene question), but then I can't explain why two adjacent full columns are not considered continuous.

Comment: I think A.S.H. has answered that nicely. **Adjacent** ranges are not the same as a **contiguous** range.

Answer (score 1):

`Intersect(Range("B:B, C:C"), Rows(1))` gives a continuous range, `$B$1:$C$1`.
`Intersect(Range("B:B, D:D"), Rows(1))` gives a non-continuous range, `$B$1,$D$1`.

Continuous ranges have only one [`Area`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213698%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Non-continuous have more than one.

When you are referring to range's cells without explicitly saying which `Area` that is, you're getting the first area by default.

The first area of `$B$1:$C$1` is `$B$1:$C$1`, the second cell of that is `$C$1`.
The first area of `$B$1,$D$1` is `$B$1`, the second cell of that is (going out of the area's boundary!) `$B$2`.

Comment: Kudos to @Rory for explaining [the rules for going out of the area's boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33015532/11683).