# Enter values in selected cells using Selection.Cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, selection

I select 3 isolated cells such as a1, f6 and g13, then run this code:

```
Selection.Cells(1) = 3
Selection.Cells(2) = 4
Selection.Cells(3) = 6
```

I expect the 3 selected cells to be filled, instead a1, a2 and a3 are filled.

Why? How can I fill the 3 cells of my selection?

Comment: why to use selection at all? why not `Range("A1").Value = 3`, `Range("F6").Value = 4` and `Range("G13").Value = 6` ? Is there a special reason you want to work with `Selection` ?

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33015612/4926357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** need to do this, then I'd still suggest moving away from `Selection` but the code you provide needs just a small tweak to work:

```
Selection.Cells.Areas(1) = 3
Selection.Cells.Areas(2) = 4
Selection.Cells.Areas(3) = 6
```

Comment: You could remove the `.Cells.` part and just use `Selection.Areas(1) = 3`.